# Compare two files line by line without comm (I need to maintain order of file 1)

Tags: text-processing, text, file-comparison, comm

File 1:

```
happy
sad
calm
palm
```

File 2:

```
palm
dream
calm
```

I want to compare the two files and display only those line that are common in both the files, but I want to maintain the order of File 2. My output should be:

```
palm
calm
```

I know I can use comm after sorting the files but I want to maintain the order. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use grep:

```
$ grep -Ff f1 f2
palm
calm
```

man grep:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular
          expressions), separated by newlines,  any  of  which  is  to  be
          matched.
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is used
          multiple times or is combined with  the  -e  (--regexp)  option,
          search  for  all  patterns  given.  The empty file contains zero
          patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Comment: Also, this should probably use `-x`.